# Acceptability of ChatGPT generated answers on Chess SE

Tags: discussion

Chess is different when it comes to forms of artificial intelligence. We use chess engines all the time (except when playing serious games) and using them to answer questions is so normal that it is more usual to make the excuse "I didn't use an engine" to highlight that any errors in presented analysis are human not silicon ones.

ChatGPT, however, is entirely different. The answers to chess questions are banal and useless. They are usually, at best, of the form "God, motherhood and apple pie are good". At their worst they are just silly and wrong. [Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/41870/revisions) is one example in response to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-are-examples-of-very-aggressive-openings). Actually, that answer is just plain wrong and illustrates just how incompetent ChatGPT is when it comes to chess.

The overall site policy is given in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide/385002#385002). It is that individual sites must decide their own specific policy as to whether such answers are acceptable but that in any case all such answers must include attribution to ChatGPT because they are not the author's own thoughts.

What do people think about this? Should we allow ChatGPT with attribution? Should we ban it? Should we allow in only certain special cases?

FWIW My view is to ban ChatGPT altogether while strongly encouraging the use of real chess-based artificial intelligence like Stockfish. LeelaZero, et al. Even GNUChess and Crafty.

Comment: Over-Meta reference: [Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/476162)

Comment: Does "banning LLM altogether" mean "banning verbatim reproduction of end-to-end LLM-generated answers", or does it cover other use cases that involve generation of the complete answer text by LLM as well? E.g. I could imagine someone answering a question based on their knowledge in bullet points, or in their native language, and then having an LLM turn this into a proper answer in English, maybe after discussing possible objections to their content with the LLM. I would expect that such workflows will often lead to better presentation and more factual answers than pure human generation.

Answer (score 7):

**Do not allow attributed ChatGPT answers for any questions**

Vote up if you agree

Comment: What is wrong with reasonable human checked GPT answers. Like with humana nswers, user will quickl y be banned for posting nonsense

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Using ChatGPT to assist you is not a problem, but simply posting what it gives you is what is not what allowed. Crediting ChatGPT for helping fill in a few gaps in your otherwise human answer is at your discretion.

Answer (score -4):

**Allow attributed ChatGPT answers for all questions**

Vote up if you agree

Answer (score -5):

I personally think that ChatGPT generated answers should be allowed, but no copy-pasting. You must check it over and change it. Also, if it really similar you must attribute it, otherwise that is plagarism

Answer (score -6):

**Allow attributed ChatGPT answers for some questions only**

Vote up if you agree and post a comment describing which type of questions to allow this